# gcc error: "unable to find a register to spill" (problems with OS's dev's inline assembly)

Tags: c, gcc, intel, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

So mates, i am learning how to make a scheduler in an intel's 80386 so please dont kill me :), i have the following code which mixes C and inline-asm:

```
__INT_HANDLERS_SECTION__ static void saveTaskContext(_str_TSS * str_TSS_task)
{
    register uint32 * eax       asm ("eax");
    register uint32 * ebx       asm ("ebx");
    register uint32 * ecx       asm ("ecx");
    register uint32 * edx       asm ("edx");

    register uint32 * esi       asm ("esi");
    register uint32 * edi       asm ("edi");
    register uint32 * ebp       asm ("ebp");
    register uint32 * esp       asm ("esp");

    asm volatile("mov eax,gs");
    str_TSS_task->GS = *eax;

    asm volatile("mov eax,fs");
    str_TSS_task->FS = *eax;

    asm volatile("mov eax,ds");
    str_TSS_task->DS = *eax;

    asm volatile("mov eax,ss");
    str_TSS_task->SS = *eax;

    asm volatile("mov eax,es");
    str_TSS_task->ES = *eax;

    asm volatile("mov eax,cr3");
    str_TSS_task->ES =  *eax;

    str_TSS_task->EDI = * edi;
    str_TSS_task->ESI = * esi;
    str_TSS_task->ESP = * esp;

    asm volatile("pop edx");
    str_TSS_task->EDX = *edx;

    asm volatile("pop ecx");
    str_TSS_task->ECX = *ecx;   

    asm volatile("pop ebx");
    str_TSS_task->EBX = *ebx;   

    asm volatile("pop eax");
    str_TSS_task->EAX = *eax;   

    asm volatile("pop eax");
    str_TSS_task->EFLAGS = *eax;    

    asm volatile("pop eax");
    str_TSS_task->CS = *eax;    

    asm volatile("pop eax");
    str_TSS_task->EIP = *eax;

    str_TSS_task->EBP = *ebp;

    return;
}  // <------------------------- LINE 515 !!!
```

I am looking forward to save the values of the registers (as the name of the function says) but when i try to compile i get the next gcc error:

```
src/handlers.c: In function ‘saveTaskContext’:
src/handlers.c:515:1: error: unable to find a register to spill
 }
 ^
src/handlers.c:515:1: error: this is the insn:
(insn 7 92 93 2 (set (reg:SI 146 [orig:88 D.1975 ] [88])
        (mem:SI (reg/f:SI 145 [orig:87 D.1974 ] [87]) [0 *_2+0 S4 A32])) src/handlers.c:470 90 {*movsi_internal}
     (expr_list:REG_DEAD (reg/f:SI 145 [orig:87 D.1974 ] [87])
        (nil)))
src/handlers.c:515: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

Any ideas how to solve it? I would really appreciate :)

edit: I forgot to say that before doing the pop's i already have in the stack (in top-down order) EIP, CS, EFLAGS, EAX, EBX, ECX and EDX

Comment: According to the [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) "The only supported use for [Local Register Variables] is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm."  Since that's not what you're doing, it's unclear whether this will work dependably. There's also [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html) "Do not expect a sequence of [Basic] asm statements to remain perfectly consecutive after compilation."  That could really muck up your code. Florian's suggestion about a pure asm routine might be your best answer.

Answer (score 2):

The i386 only has eight general-purpose registers.  You assign specific roles to all of them.  As a result, GCC is not able to find a workable register allocation.  (It needs some registers to implement indirect loads and stores.)  Furthermore, ESP and EBP are used in the function prologue and likely have been clobbered before your code runs.  It is also odd that a register variable called `eax` would contain a *pointer* to a value that is then read.

You will have to write this code in a separate assembler routine, not as C inline assembly.  It is also unclear whether you can achieve what you want with the ABI calling convention.